# Security for Outswinging Door (Patio) Not Sliding door

Tags: doors, security

I live on the 1st floor (Ground floor) in an apartment complex. The door opens outside into the patio not inside to the apartment. How do I secure the door while we are inside the apartment?
Any security bars or DOOR Jammers etc?

For front door we use this now: [Brinks 675-83001 Home Security Commercial Door Jammer (on Amazon.com)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NP0E7SI) (This is works perfect for door opens inside/inswing).

Comment: Step 1, make sure the door has non-removable henge pins or concealed hinges.  Without those, most anything else you do is moot.

Comment: @BrockAdams What are non-removable henge pins or concealed hinges? Any picture samples?

Comment: Oops!  That should have been "hinge" (I blame Naruto).  Anyway, those terms are very Googleable ([Example](http://www.stanleydoorhinges.com/index.asp?Mode=SAH006_11)).

Answer (score 2):

Just short of doing something like below, I think the best you can make sure of is:

- Steel door
- Secured hinges (As Brock Adams suggested - non-removable pins or concealed)
- A deadbolt
- Reinforced latches, or at least well installed.
- Not excessive clearance between the door and the frame that would allow anything between to mess with the latch (A deadbolt also takes care of this)

[image: Pooh bear]